# What needs to be escaped, or further changed, to execute this in Java's regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following line of code:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("CREATE TABLE ([^ ]*) \\(").matcher("CREATE TABLE DeliveryPointAddress (");
```

The resulting `Matcher` does not contain a match, or more importantly, does not contain the table name.

What do I need to change to get a match on `"DeliveryPointAddress"` in group 1?

Comment: To downvoters? you people never learnt something without making silly mistakes or unknown one... +1 upped.

Comment: This is a common mistake when using Pattern/Matcher! +1

Comment: The actual problem in your code is nothing to do with the question title.

Comment: And the question in your title is answered in the Javadoc.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Ignoring the line of code for a minute. It looks like you want to change the table name in a create statement - is that the task?

Comment: I have an SQL query and I am extracting the table name so I can use it to build some hibernate configs and PoJos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm no psychic, but I believe your problem is that you aren't calling [`find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) prior to querying the matcher:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("CREATE TABLE ([^ ]*) \\(").matcher(
                "CREATE TABLE DeliveryPointAddress (");
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

```
DeliveryPointAddress
```

Note that `find()` returns a boolean indicating whether a match was found, so normally you would do something along the lines of

```
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

But the idea is the same: call `find()` first!